# Unable to perform postgres migrations when using docker compose

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I have **postgres & pgadmin** running in the same network & a node-express app running locally `localhost:3000`.

I am using `sequelize` orm.

After running the migration using `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` it is showing

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.1, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.6.5]

Loaded configuration file "database/config/config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20210814120300-1_create_user: migrating =======
== 20210814120300-1_create_user: migrated (0.021s)

== 20210929114301-2_update_user: migrating =======
== 20210929114301-2_update_user: migrated (0.017s)
```

**It is showing that the migrations have happened successfully but the migrated changes have not taken effect in the postgres db running inside docker container**

For example this is a part of my migration file

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Users", {
      ...
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: "email",
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      // newly added fields
      profileImage: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: "profile_image",
        allowNull: true,
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: "background_image",
        allowNull: true,
      },
      bio: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
      // =========
      hashedPassword: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: "hashed_pass",
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Users");
  },
};
```

As you can see in the below image the table is not updated after the `email` there is `hashed_pass` & the columns `profile_image, background_image, bio` are absent

[image: The table is not updated]

What docker concept will be used to implement this bcz. This is the docker-compose file for the following

```
version: "3.0"

services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pg_admin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=....@gmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 80:80

  db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=test_db
    ports:
      - 5430:5432
    volumes:
      - "C:/Users/Perry/Documents/workspace/cp-back/dumped/users:/infile"
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

**What needs to be done so that when i execute the migrations locally the migrations happens in the postgres db running in the docker container**

Comment: show us database/config/config.js

Comment: ```js
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    url: process.env.DEV_DATABASE_URL,
    dialect: "postgres",
  },
  test: {
    url: process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL,
    dialect: "postgres",
  },
  production: {
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    dialect: "postgres",
  },
};
```
However this is not a problem with database/config/config.js. It is working fine with locally installed postgres